# ROR code sends many mails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, function, session

I am having following ROR code

```
def func (point,c,r)          
  res=isPointInCircle(point,c,r) #returns  true/ false
 if res=='false'               
   AlertMailer.geofence('mail@gmail.com').deliver
 end
end
```

func is called for every 2 minutes with different point.

isPointInCircle checks point is within circle or not .Returns true false.

I want to send mail when the point is first time outside or inside the circle.

- Means if initially point is inside for 1 hrs.

  no mail
- if it goes outside

  I want single mail to be sent which does not happen,

  because func is called every 2 min.
  so emails are sent every 2 minutes which i dont want .

So how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the previous status is the same as the current status, and only send the mail if there has been a change (the point is inside the circle and it was outside before, or vice versa).

```
def func(point, c, r)
  status = point_in_circle?(point, c, r)
  if last_status != status
    AlertMailer.geofence('mail@gmail.com').deliver
  end
end
```

It's hard to say how to implement `last_status` without knowing more about your app. If there were a `Point` model, I might add `in_circle?` as an instance method. Then you could get the previous point from the database and compare the two:

```
def check_point_status(current, previous, c, r)
  if current.in_circle?(c, r) != previous.in_circle?(c, r)
    AlertMailer.geofence('mail@gmail.com').deliver
  end
end
```

A couple of pointers: Ruby usually uses `snake_case` not `camelCase` for variables and functions, and "predicate" methods (returning true/false) are typically named with a question mark at the end to indicate that they are yes/no questions. You wouldn't have needed the comment in your code because it would have been obvious that `point_in_circle?` returns true or false.

Also your code suggests your function returns `"true"` or `"false"` as strings, which is a really bad idea! If you used the actual boolean values `true` or `false`, you could have written your original code as

```
def func(point, c, r)          
  unless point_in_circle?(point, c, r)             
    AlertMailer.geofence('mail@gmail.com').deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: Good ...Awsome suggession..Thanks